# How does this recursive function get to this output?

Tags: java, function, if-statement, recursion

When I run this piece of code for n=5 the output I get is "5 3 1 1 3 5"
I get the 5 3 1 part but after that n=-1 but when I run the code with a debugger it when n=-1 it goes to the line after `numbers(n-2);`i.e `System.out.prt(n+ "");` even though that statement is contained in the if block.

Why does this happen?

```
public void numbers(int n)
{
    if(n>0)
    {
        System.out.print(n+" ");
        numbers(n-2);
        System.out.print(n+" ");
    }
}
```

TLDR : when n=-1  `System.out.prt(n+ "");`even though it is within the if block which only runs when n>0.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens behind the scenes, for `n == 5`:

```
numbers(5);
    if(5 > 0)--> true : 
        System.out.print(5 + " "); // (1)
        numbers(3);
        |   if(3 > 0)--> true : 
        |       System.out.print(3 + " "); // (2)
        |       numbers(1);
        |       |   if(1 > 0)--> true : 
        |       |       System.out.print(1 + " "); // (3)
        |       |       numbers(-1);
        |       |       System.out.print(1 + " "); // (4)
        |       System.out.print(3 + " "); // (5)
        System.out.print(5 + " "); // (6)
```

Notice how each number **is supposed to be** printed twice:

```
System.out.print(n + " "); // print once
numbers(n-2);
System.out.print(n + " "); // print twice
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why after after printing 1 for the second time it prints 3 and 5 again?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the final System.out.print(n+" ");
After the recursive numbers call it comes back with the original value for n and prints this again.

It bubbles back from the deepest level where it prints 1 two times up to the call with number 3, which is printed again, and also 5 is printed again.

If you want it to update the value after it is printed the first time you will have to update the variable n by performing n-=2 instead of n-2

Answer (score 0):

```
    5 first system.out then number(5-2)
    |
    ----> 3  first system.out then number(5-2)
          |
           ----->1 first system.out then number(5-2)
                 (smaller than 0) , returning
                 |
                 1 second system.out
                 |
           3<----  second system.out
           |
5<---------  second system.out
```

Answer (score 0):

after n=-1, the recursive call will end and return back to the caller method to continue. first commands it found is print.

If you try to debug with the debugger, you will see how rational it is.

Comment: Ahh Okay! But why does it add 2 each time it prints?!

Comment: because it will go in reverse order, old commands were saved in a queue order, last in first out. so it doesn't add 2, its just print the value of n which is the value before you deduct 2 each time.

Comment: by the way, you didn't exit the if statement yet when you reach n=-1, you were just in deeper level of recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Java maintain method call into stack and as first 5,3,1 gets printed after which method call resume execution for remaining calls and prints 1,3,5 from stack(last call in stack get's picked up first).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the recursion stack.

stack representation with and output flow:

```
             ------------------------->
             5           3            1
num(5)-->  num(3) --> num(1) --> num(-1) --> void
             5           3            1
             <-------------------------
```

Now since numbers(-1) does not satisfy the if condition, the program control comes out of the if block, and returns void. 
Start popping out the stack now (recursion):
5 3 1 1 3 5. That's what the output you get, and is expected.