# Why output change when i change cout position after decrementing my function?

Tags: c++, recursion, output

Here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
int x;
void gad(int x)
{
  if(x==0)
      return;
  else{

  std::cout<<"geek"<<" ";
  std::cout<<"for geeks ";

   gad(x-1);
  }
}
int main()
{
  gad(3);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is this

> `geek for geeks geek for geeks geek for geeks`

Now if the change the position of 2nd `std::cout`
From

```
std::cout<<"geek"<<" ";
  std::cout<<"for geeks ";

   gad(x-1);
```

to

```
   std::cout<<"geek"<<" ";
   gad(x-1);
   std::cout<<"for geeks ";
```

The output that came is this

> `geek geek geek for geeks for geeks for geeks`

**My question is why changing the position of `std::cout` changes the output like that?**

I thought if I put `cout` after the function, due to recursion it won't give "for geeks" and come out of the recursive loop due to the `if` statement.

Comment: Because gad() is recurisvely called and the std::cout <<"for geeks " occurrs after the function is returned and will hit that line next.. Just step through it with an input of 1 or 2 and write it on paper and go through it line by line and it'll make sense

Comment: What did you expect would happen when you changed the order of those lines?

Comment: @JaMiT i thought if i put `cout` after the function due to recursion it won't give " for geeks " and come out of the recursive loop due to if statement

Comment: @Zoro-TheScar That should be part of the question so that people can directly address your misunderstanding of how recursion works. (Comments are subject to disappear at any time.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? The first two paragraphs of [A: What happens when recursion is called twice in a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37069617) to start, then [How does this recursive function get to this output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725881/how-does-this-recursive-function-get-to-this-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the first sentence, then going into a recursive call to the same function which will, in return, print the first sentence and go to another recursive call...etc.
After the last function returns, it will continue with `x=1` to print the second sentence...etc.
To visualize what happens, this will be the call stack:

x=3 ---> print first statement

x=2 ---> print first statement

x=1 ---> print first statement

x=0 ---> return

x=1 ---> continue to print second statement and terminate

x=2 ---> continue to print second statement and terminate

x=3 ---> continue to print second statement and terminate

Comment: if x came equal to zero because of recursive calling and it will came out of the gad() funtion because of the if statement then how will it print "for geeks" ?

Comment: @Zoro-TheScar `return` statement will terminate only the current function the call stack, which is `gad(0)`. So, `gad(1)` will continue working, then `gad(2)`, and lastly `gad(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are printing both before making your recursive call.
Whereas in the second scenario, you are first printing 'geeks', and making the recursive call, which again prints 'geeks' and so on, until it returns null, and then 'for geeks' is printed as it is sequentially the next statement after the recursive call.